# How to change the default "edit externally" app for photos in lyx?

Tags: graphics, lyx

I'm trying to quickly add pics into my documents but when I edit the photo in paint it just doesn't cut it. is there a way to change the app I go to when I click the edit externally?

the menu:

[image]

if you know how to do it plz write  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Tools > Preferences > File Formats, then under "Format" select the type of pictures you are including. Then, change the "Editor" combo box. In the following screenshot, it shows that my editor for PNG is set to "gimp":

[image: custom editor]